# Стилизация chekbox в table (checkbox и label находятся в разных контейнерах)

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть `table` с `checkbox`

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <input onclick="zapiszKoszyk(24,this.checked ? 1 : 0);" name="akcept_dane_osobowe" id="akcdosbid" value="1" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="margin: 5px; text-align: left">
            <label for="akcdosbid">text text text text text text text text</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

как стилизировать `input[type="checkbox"]` если `label` находиться в другом `td`

код генерирует cms магазина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  $this.wrap('<label class="check-box" for="'+ $this.attr("id")+'"></label>');  
  $('<span class="ch-style"></span>').insertAfter($this);
  
});
```

```css
.check-box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.check-box input {
   position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.ch-style {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    margin-right: 11px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.ch-style:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    background-position: -90px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
         -o-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
}

.check-box input:checked ~ .ch-style:after{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
         -o-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>    
          <input name="akcept_dane_osobowe" id="akcdosbid" value="1" type="checkbox">
        
      </td>
      <td>
          <div style="margin: 5px; text-align: left">
              <label for="akcdosbid">text text text text text text text text</label>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо все работает

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете спокойно использовать несколько `label` для одного чекбокса, например:

```css
.checkbox {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}

.checkboxt+.label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox:not(checked) {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox:not(checked)+.label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}

.checkbox:not(checked)+.label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: #CDD1DA;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.checkbox:not(checked)+.label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transition: all .2s;
}

.checkbox:checked+.label:before {
  background: #9FD468;
}

.checkbox:checked+.label:after {
  left: 26px;
}

.checkbox:focus+.label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class=checkbox onclick="zapiszKoszyk(24,this.checked ? 1 : 0);" name="akcept_dane_osobowe" id="akcdosbid" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <label class=label for="akcdosbid"></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div style="margin: 5px; text-align: left">
          <label for="akcdosbid">text text text text text text text text</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```